# Can I create a conditional literal?

Tags: f#, literals, type-providers

In order to create a Json provider I need to pass a literal with the path. There are several people working on the project from different locations, and the paths are different in each case. (Actually only the beginning of each path). I tried to create a literal with pattern matching but the compiler does not accept it. Is there another way to do this?

My failed attempt is below:

```
open FSharp.Data

[<Literal>]
let bitbucketRoot = // Error message: This is not a valid constant expression
    let computerName = Environment.MachineName 
    match computerName with
    | "DESKTOP-G3OF32U" -> "C:\\Users\\Fernando"
    | "HPW8" -> @"H:\Dropbox\"
    | _ -> failwith "Unknown computer"

[<Literal>] // Error message: This is not a valid constant expression
let projDataPath = bitbucketRoot + @"Bitbucket\VSProjects\Fractal10\Fractal10\data\" 

[<Literal>] // Error message: This is not a valid constant expression
let jsonPath = projDataPath + "fractal.json"
type PathInfo = JsonProvider<Sample=jsonPath>
```

Comment: This won't work - the whole idea is that a literal needs to be known at compile time - so you can't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a conditional literal  as the other comments point it out. However this is a fairly frequent use case and the way to deal with it is as follows:

```
#r @"..\packages\FSharp.Data\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.dll"
open FSharp.Data
open System
open System.IO

[<Literal>]
let JsonSource = __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + @"\test.json"

type JSonType = JsonProvider<JsonSource>

let json1 = JSonType.GetSamples()

let anotherPath = @"C:\tmp"
let anotherJson = anotherPath + @"\test.json"
let json2 = JSonType.Load(anotherJson)
```

The `__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__` directive will point to the project root (just display it in the REPL) and then you can add the filename to it and make that a literal. If you check in this file into a git repo, then everyone who checks it out can have it in a relative path, and you can refer it when generating the type. When actually using the type or referring to the full file you can just use the `.Load()` method to load any file, and this doesn't have to be a literal.

There is actually a second way, which could work for you depending on the circumstances, compile a sample, and distribute it as a .dll. You can refer to this and use it directly without having access to the actual file. Please see the [Using the JSON Provider in a Library](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html) section at the end of the documentation.

I have not tried referring to the json in a config file, it might also be possible.

Comment: Thaks. I will be looking into the "Using the JSON Provider in a Library" section. But just for the record I want to explain that I got this problem precisely because `__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__` does `not` necessarily point to the project root, although this is true in the most common case. I explain: My code was working fine until I moved the .fs file that creates my JSON provider and the necessary literals to another folder (so that it could be used to other projects) and added it to my project via a link. In that case `__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__` points to this other folder, not to my project's root.

Comment: @Soldalma I see. You might want to also look at `ResolutionFolder` parameter in the  [API doc](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/reference/fsharp-data-jsonprovider.html) , but I assume that has to be  a literal as well. Another way I use is to define the connection string in the config file and I don't check that one in. This depends on the TP though. Finally you can just use the [JsonParser](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonValue.html), as that one is not a TP you can load anything. Or another Json lib like Newtonsoft, fsharplu, chiron, etc.

Comment: Ok, in the end my solution was to bring the .fs file back into my project, out of the library folder, so it is no longer linked. In this way I and all others involved in the project can use `__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__`.

Answer (score 3):

I would advise that you store it in source control and make it a path relative to your project root, assuming you are working out of a common source control repository.

Either that, or host the sample on a public URL. (I wouldn't actually recommend this because including it in your source repository allows versioning and doesn't publicly expose your data)

Comment: @Soldalma you can use __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ or even just ../file.JSON for the sample that is shared by everyone who works on the solution.  and for other paths just use the .Load method. This is the typical for all TPs.